# Android soft keyboard showing up on webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

There are a lot of questions about how to display `Soft Keyboard` in android `WebView`. I have a problem quite opposite of that.

For some reason the `Soft Keyboard` keeps showing up every time I click anything (just some text for example) in the WebView content. There are no input fields in the view, nor are there any `EditText` elements.

This problem exists only when using Android 4.3 (not an issue with older versions or with 4.4).

I have tried most of the solutions I have found and the only way I can get that thing to not appear is using

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in the layout file.

That causes other problems though - now if I add a select field to the HTML file in WebView window - after selection is made an error is produced and focus does not return to the webview (so can't use it any more after that).

> 01-07 10:59:49.848: W/InputMethodManagerService(287): Window already focused, ignoring 
>   focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41a0b510 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41771d70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Pretty weird one. I removed the focusableInTouchMode thing from the layout definition and added this to JavaScript in my WebView content:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function() { 
  document.activeElement.blur(); 
});
```